# If there is no additional readinessgates, can we assume that "Ready" must be true when "ContainersReady" is true?

Tags: kubernetes

As for the state judgment of pod ready, if no additional readinessgates are declared, only four default conditions type("Initialized", "Ready", "ContainersReady", "PodScheduled") are used to judge ，can we think that type "Ready"'s status must be "True" when type "ContainersReady"'s status is "True"?

This is an example of pod status：

```
"status":{
                    "phase":"Running",
                    "conditions":[
                        {
                            "type":"Initialized",
                            "status":"True",
                            "lastProbeTime":null,
                            "lastTransitionTime":"2021-01-30T10:25:06Z"
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"Ready",
                            "status":"False",
                            "lastProbeTime":null,
                            "lastTransitionTime":"2021-01-30T10:25:04Z",
                            "reason":"ContainersNotReady",
                            "message":"containers with unready status: [frontgateway]"
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"ContainersReady",
                            "status":"False",
                            "lastProbeTime":null,
                            "lastTransitionTime":"2021-01-30T10:25:04Z",
                            "reason":"ContainersNotReady",
                            "message":"containers with unready status: [frontgateway]"
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"PodScheduled",
                            "status":"True",
                            "lastProbeTime":null,
                            "lastTransitionTime":"2021-01-30T10:25:04Z"
                        }
                    ],
                    "hostIP":"10.230.20.15",
                    "podIP":"172.20.100.124",
                    "startTime":"2021-01-30T10:25:04Z",
                    "initContainerStatuses":[
                        {
                            "name":"sysctl",
                            "state":{
                                "terminated":{
                                    "exitCode":0,
                                    "reason":"Completed",
                                    "startedAt":"2021-01-30T10:25:05Z",
                                    "finishedAt":"2021-01-30T10:25:05Z",
                                    "containerID":"docker://16053d1ec304999d2ade01dbc0f8365f747889511230dde319e7d761fcc091ff"
                                }
                            },
                            "lastState":{

                            },
                            "ready":true,
                            "restartCount":0,
                            "image":"xxx/middleware/sysctl:latest",
                            "imageID":"docker-pullable://xxx/middleware/sysctl@sha256:4c83e8db97e735c01061dcd457f64675835af5eef273095686c5cc32582e1b2d",
                            "containerID":"docker://16053d1ec304999d2ade01dbc0f8365f747889511230dde319e7d761fcc091ff"
                        }
                    ],
                    "containerStatuses":[
                        {
                            "name":"frontgateway",
                            "state":{
                                "waiting":{
                                    "reason":"CrashLoopBackOff",
                                    "message":"Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=frontgateway pod=frontgateway-796c59788d-lphtb_ligl-it-self(fc8ac2b3-ed6e-4339-83cc-c00c5fd42344)"
                                }
                            },
                            "lastState":{
                                "terminated":{
                                    "exitCode":1,
                                    "reason":"Error",
                                    "startedAt":"2021-01-30T11:05:13Z",
                                    "finishedAt":"2021-01-30T11:05:32Z",
                                    "containerID":"docker://63fdded29498e6b877f895e547aeee68aaf7539f5dc5844110adc45b4a7a5435"
                                }
                            },
                            "ready":false,
                            "restartCount":12,
                            "image":"xxx/ligl-dev/frontgateway:integration.7.0.0.0.36",
                            "imageID":"docker-pullable://xxx/ligl-dev/frontgateway@sha256:1f5d83e18e3b9c9b8168f9c9552a27d48a514408329ff6d6ae6877deae1dfda5",
                            "containerID":"docker://63fdded29498e6b877f895e547aeee68aaf7539f5dc5844110adc45b4a7a5435"
                        }
                    ],
                    "qosClass":"Burstable"
                }
```

[image]

Please forgive my pool English.

Answer (score 1):

Readiness Probes basically check your containers are ready and able to do productive work. So if type `ContainersReady`'s status is `True` then `Ready`'s status also be `True`.